# Python SQL Select drops leading 0 from string column

Tags: python, mysql, sql, select, mysql-connector-python

A Python 3.7 SQL SELECT request, using MYSQL Connector, is returning a list of integers from an SQL table that is made up of an INT column and a TEXT column. Although the TEXT column is made up of numbers defined as strings, some of the cells have leading 0's, which are dropped in the Python query.

For example, consider the following SQL table row, where the "text" column is set as TEXT:

```
id text
1  03034999
```

I'm using the following code to return this row:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
select_row = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE text LIKE "0303____" LIMIT 1'
cursor.execute(select_row)
result = cursor.fetchall()
## output: [(1, 3034999)]
```

The leading 0 in "03034999" is dropped. How can I avoid this happening?

EDIT: Using a VARCHAR(255) column instead of a TEXT column solves this issue, and the leading 0's are not dropped anymore:

```
## output: [(1, '03034999')]
```

Comment: Does the trailing zero get dropped or does the _leading_ zero get dropped?  In any case, this isn't reproducible, and if `text` really be a text column type, then this should not be happening.

Comment: Another note: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless.  You need to provide MySQL with some order to make limit have any meaning.

Comment: *The leading 0 in "03034999" is dropped.* That's not MySQL. Check why python treats this value as a number, not a string, and how to fix it.